# React Native Rounded View with child

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image: Circular View]

How I can draw UI like analog clock in react native, I want to draw circular Scale/Ruler, where user can select his size by moving circle. I want to mark small trips or lines on the border of the circle.

The above image might give some idea

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Provide at least some code..

Comment: i dont have any specific code for that, I have just created one rounded view with some border radius, and trying to add some line to show as marker lines , I need just one idea about how i can implement this type view , you might be know about analog clock , Same UI i want to design in react native

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start with exploring some similar kind of projects to get an idea?

Ref:

https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-slider

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-analog-clock